# Looking for simple examples of how to calculate type III and type IV SS

Tags: references, random-effects-model, unbalanced-classes, sums-of-squares, intraclass-correlation

I have data collected on five species of fish at half a dozen locations in a lake over four years.  The categories are not (at all) fully crossed, and I have a lot of empty cells due to logistical challenges with the sampling.  I'm interested in comparing the effect of location and year on the variance.  Despite the empty cells, it seems to me (after extensive reading) that it should be possible to do that comparison by using a corrected SS (Type III or Type IV), and calculating intraclass correlations.  But I don't really understand how a Type III or a Type IV SS are calculated, and as a result, I can't assess if those are the right tools to answer my questions.

So what I'm looking for is **simple examples of how one calculates Type III and Type IV SS, preferably by hand** (because I learn best by doing arithmetic and drawing plots), **or in R** (but I can muddle through SAS if necessary).  I've looked a lot but haven't found anything really helpful.  Any suggestions (tutorials, examples, book chapters) would be welcome.

(I'd also welcome any other suggestions for strategies to tackle this question given the (albeit cursory) description of the data above!)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I cannot comment due to the reputation.

I found [here](http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/~fscholer/anova.php) has a great discussion about Type I, II and III SS in `R`. I am not familiar with Type IV SS, but I believe [here](http://core.ecu.edu/psyc/wuenschk/SAS/SS1234.docx%E2%80%8E) is a good additional tutorial about it, using `MODEL` statement in `SAS`’ `PROC GLM`.

The second tutorial pointed out, "Type IV SS are identical to Type III SS for designs with no missing cells, and when you have missing cells you really should not be doing a factorial analysis.  Although you can do one with Type IV SS, the solution is not unique -- better to collapse across or eliminate categories in order to avoid the missing cells."